# How can I set the values of a dynamic set of range inputs in React?

Tags: reactjs, input, onchange

I have an array that I want to loop through and create range inputs out of.

```
const ratings = [
  {
    title: 'Category One'
  },
  {
    title: 'Category Two'
  },
  {
    title: 'Category Three'
  }
];

const renderRatings = ratings.map((rating, key) => {
  return (
    <div className="rating" key={key}>
      <h3>{rating.title}</h3>
      <div className="rating__num">0</div>
      <input className="rating__range" type="range" min="0" max="10" />
    </div>
  );
});
```

How would I update each `rating__num` to reflect the value of it's `rating__range` sibling?

Comment: Paste the ratings array data.

Comment: adding `return` in front of `<div>` would be a start. You need one if you're writing an arrow function with a block body, rather than a one liner.

Comment: As Mike salid, first add return before of the div with the classname "rating" or wrap everything up in parentheses to return this jsx element in ratings variable

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot the `return` statement. I've added it but I'm still unsure of how to update the values in `rating__num`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just needed to create a new component out of the rating, so it has it's own state.

```
function Rating(props) {

  const [ratingValue, setRatingValue] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="rating" key={key}>
      <h3>{rating.title}</h3>
      <div className="rating__num">{ratingValue}</div>
      <input
        className="rating__range"
        type="range"
        min="0"
        max="10"
        onChange={(e) => setRatingValue(e.currentTarget.value)}
      />
    </div>
  ):
}

function MyComponent(props) {

  const renderRatings = ratings.map((rating, key) => {
    return (
      <Rating key={key} rating={rating} />
    );
  });

  return (
    {renderRatings()}
  );

}
```